# Заголовок php запросов

Tags: php, include

Ребята очень нужна помощь. Сдают нервы.
Есть файл index.php, куда приходит извне url в формате к примеру svoloch.fun/?id=1027/app=7
достаю оттуда данные 1027 и 7
В этом же файле в конце `include_once 'PUT.php';`

В файле PUT часть обработки данных и в конце `require_once 'report.php';`

В report.php в начале

```
require_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
require_once ('main.php');
require_once ('PUT.php');
```

в конце `include 'nnn.php';`

Суть в том, что есть форма в nnn.php при заполнении полей которой - происходит отправка данных в PUT.php и страница обновляется. 
И всё, пропадают все данные, так как вместо `svoloch.fun/?id=1027/app=7` получается `svoloch.fun/index.php`

Помогите пожалуйста!!! Нет сил моих больше.
Всё перепробовал. Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы данные 1027 и 7 не пропадали при обновлении страницы.
В файле main.php запросы по API которые и должны содержать значения из первого $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Ниже содержание файла index.php

```
<?php

$url1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url1;
$pieces = explode("/", $url1);
$Preuserid = $pieces[1];
$userid = (int) filter_var($Preuserid, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$PreloanId = $pieces[2];
$loanId = (int) filter_var($PreloanId, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $userid;
echo $loanId;
include_once 'PUT.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> происходит отправка данных в PUT.php и страница обновляется.

Как вы обновляете страницу?
Может вы там явно указываете:

```
header("Location: /index.php");
```

Comment: Нет, не указываю, в nnn.php запоняется форма POST, которая сама переходит на PUT.php <br/>
        <form name="form" action="PUT.php" method="post"> <br/>
header нигде не указаны.

Comment: Странно форма должна просто перенаправить не на index.php, а на PUT.php. Код PUT.php бы увидеть.

Comment: Полностью не влезает.
Вот часть
    <?php


if (isset($_POST["p1"])) {
    $FIOClientP = $_POST['p1'];
} else {
    $FIOClientP = "";
}

if (isset($_POST["p2"])) {
    $FIOCoobP = $_POST['p2'];
} else {
    $FIOCoobP = "";
}

if (isset($_POST["p3"])) {
    $EmpClientP = $_POST['p3'];
} else {
    $EmpClientP = "";
}

require_once 'report.php';

?>

Других скриптов и т.п. нет.

Сам не могу понять почему на index.php перенаправляет.

Comment: а что в report.php?

Comment: <?php
require_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
require_once ('main.php');
require_once ('PUT.php');

ОБРАБОТКА данных в  PHPExcel 

Никаких дополнений или сриптов или headers там нет, которые вообще рендерили бы на какую либо другую страницу. А в конце файла



include 'nnn.php';

?>

Comment: а в .httaccess нет никаких редиректов?

Comment: Нет, там ничего такого нет. Совсем нервы сдают уже...............

Comment: Поставьте exit(); в начале PUT.php. Получится ли редирект.

Comment: Тогда и форма вообще не загрузится.
Будет запускаться только index.php и всё.

Comment: в PUT.php перед require_once 'report.php' if (!empty($_POST)){ exit(); }

Comment: В общем не помогло.

Есть может возможность данные, которые были первыми входящими сохранить. А если еще раз на эту даже страницу попадал, то не считывать  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?

Comment: храните переменные в сессии. самый быстрый вариант для Вас